# Expand Collapse buttons in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, typescript

I intend to create multiple expand/collapse button at the bottom of each article that I display in a stream using AngularJS. 
This is what my page structure looks like:

```
<h1>Heading of the Page</h1>
<div class="item-content-wrapper">

<div class="item-content-block">
<article id="item-content" class="item-content">Some very long text goes here.
</article>
</div>
<div class="action-bar-wrapper">
    <div class="action-bar">
        <div class="action-button">
            <icon name="expand">E</icon>
        </div>
        <div class="action-button">
            <icon name="share">S</icon>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have multiple `item-content-blocks` and I want to expand and collapse each block using AngularJS (Please DO NOT use jQuery anywhere).
Since there will be multiple blocks, with same Class names and everything, a scalable code will be needed.

I am just beginning with AngularJS, so any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since there will be multiple blocks, with same Class names and everything, a scalable code will be needed.

you essentially should have each block driven off an item in your view model. Just an an `expanded` (boolean) option to each item. Then you can drive css classes off of it using `ngClass`.

## More

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass